# Search results not includes custom fields

Tags: search, crawling, managed-property

I have content type on my site with 3 custom columns defined:

- "Corporate sponsored" - Single line of text column
- "Country" - Yes/No column
- "Customer Name" - Managed metadata column

This content type is used in my custom list. Now, I want to use SharePoint Search API to fetch items from this list. I use "SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool V2" from Codeplex to test search API.

I encounter some problems with crawling/indexing my columns:

- Yes/No column was successfully crawled, and managed property "CorporatesponsoredOWSBOOL" was created. It also returned by Search API. This field is OK.
- Managed metadata column was crawled, and managed property "owstaxIdCountry" was created. But when I try to fetch it's value using Search API, this field does not appear in search results at all.
- Single line of text column was not crawled, no managed property was created. It also does not appear in search results.

I use SharePoint 2013 Online developer trial subscription.

My search query looks like this:

```
~/_api/search/query?querytext='edu'&selectproperties='CorporatesponsoredOWSBOOL%2cowstaxIdCountry%2cCountry%2cCustomerName%2cCustomer_x0020_Name%2cTitle'
```

Comment: You can always create a Managed property yourself, mapped to the crawled property created when SharePoint first indexes content in your custom columns: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/03/06/from-site-column-to-managed-property-what-s-up-with-that.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren, the problem that crawled property was not created for text column.

Comment: Make sure you have added content to one of the items in that specific text column, then do a full crawl

Comment: @RobertLindgren, yep, there are data in all custom columns. I cannot find where i can manage full crawl schedule in my SharePoint Online tenant. I can only schedule my list to be reindexed.

Comment: Ah, if it is in Online all you can do is patiently wait I'm afraid

Comment: You identify `Corporate Sponsored` as a Text column, `Country` as a Yes/No, and `Customer Name` as Managed Metadata. But when you describe your results, you've put `Corporate Sponsored` with Yes/No and `Country` with Managed Metadata. This makes it very difficult to determine how your results actually relate to your expectations, which may be part of why this question hasn't been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered a similar situation but managed to solve it by creating new managed property for each of the fields and mapping the custom fields to the respective new managed properties.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,

SK